# Show timer for complete Android application.

Tags: android, mobile, timer, timertask

Can anyone tell me best way to show timer on every screen of android application.
Like it is one timer on every screen.

I wanna show that user can use application for one hour not more than that.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Inside the main activity, have a timer layout and fragment layout. For each screen, load the fragment with a new layout.

Have a thread updating the timer, when its time out you can exit the activity or perform other actions

**Update 2:**
Check this [Event Bus Library](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus), this might fit your purpose

Comment: thanks shiv actually I can not take another activity as fragments.Because my inner activity is having side panel not the first activity.

Comment: In that case, You can have a back ground task keep updating timer in shared preference, and the screens can just show that. You might need some sort of Java observer pattern logic here, so that the screen can refresh the value when the counter change. This is one of the solution, but not probably the best solution.

Comment: Yep.. I am also looking for the some pattern that can change UI on regular basis. I thinking about local broadcast receiver.

Comment: @LuminiousAndroid: Updated my answer with Event Bus Library link, that might help you

Answer (score 1):

It might be a good alternative to show timer as ongoing notification, this way you don't need to stack to the Activty UI, and you don't waste space on the device screen.

Answer (score 1):

best option is to use alarm manager
set alarm manager +1 hours of current time(at launch of app)
and use broadcast receiver
to close app after 1 hour.

To display time on screen its unto you and your logic.. but you have to maintain time during change of fragment and activity.